# Problem with assembly DevExpress.Web-AspxEditor

Tags: c#, devexpress-mvc

I have recently installed the DevExpress 22.1.7 package, but I am unable to find the `DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditor` assembly. I have checked that I have the latest version and I have also checked that the assembly is not in the GAC.

I have also tried to install the package again but it is still missing. Has anyone else experienced this issue or know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Why don't you ask DevExpress support directly? If anyone - they would know ....